# Mocking Eloquent model with Mockery on Laravel (Lumen) doesn't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mockery

Pretty new to PHP, so forgive me if I missed something obvious.

I'm currently using Lumen (which is basically a basic Laravel, with only core dependencies) and Eloquent to manage persistent entities.

I want to write a Unit Test where I need to call a function which, at some point do an Eloquent query like this :

```
$errorMailRecipients = User::where('id_role',  1)
        ->where('some_value', 1)
        ->whereNotNull('email_addr');
```

My User.class, is a basic Eloquent entity :

```
    class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, JWTSubject
    {
       use Authenticatable, Authorizable, Eloquence, Mappable;

       const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
       const UPDATED_AT = 'modification_date';

       /** Eloquent model configuration */
       protected $connection = 'database_name';
       protected $table = 'user';
       protected $primaryKey = 'id';

      // other stuff mapping, functions, etc ...
}
```

So, I created a test and trying, with Mockery, to mock this specific query :

```
class ImportTest extends TestCase
{

    public function test_should_send_error_mail_when_receiving_empty_request()
    {
        // Given
        $controller = new ImportController();

        $mockedRecipients = // <- some Collection containing static data
        $mock = Mockery::mock(User::class, function ($mock) use ($mockedRecipients) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('where')->once()->andReturn($mockedRecipients);
        });
        $this->app->instance('App\Models\User', $mock);

        // When
        $controller->importDevices(new Request());

        // Then
    }
 }
```

I tried many variants, and to decompose mocking into multiple lines :

```
    $mock = Mockery::mock(User::class);
    $this->app->instance('User', $mock);
    $mock->shouldReceive('where')->once()->andReturn($mockedRecipients);
```

Also tried to remove the ->once(), and read the following guides :

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking
- http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/alternative_should_receive_syntax.html

But so far, I kept having the following error when executing PHP Unit test :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused ...

Because, yeah, I don't have local database and it's still trying to hit it. Any thoughts ?
Thank you

Comment: I would call my self an expert in Mocking and testing a laravel project seen it in multiple professional projects. It is a waste to mock query functionality, instead i would suggest using Sqllite memory db for it? if you wanna go that route i can show you. Usually people just setup their ci environment to run mysql tbh these days and run it local when testing locally.

Comment: And the reason it is not working is due to it being called statically

Comment: Ok thanks for your insights :) I come from the Java environment, and I'm very used to mock database queries with mockito library. I ran across multiple answers like yours, and I don't really agree. For Integration Testing, I'm totally ok to run an in memory db, to put in sets of data and test a feature from the endpoint, to the expected result. But, in my case, I want to test specific little pieces of code related to one function.

Comment: It depends on the efficiency of the mocking lib, but to my mind, it's far more lightweight to just mock a minimum response (like 2 object with few fields) instead of running a DB, insert data, cleanup data, etc ...

Comment: Laravel has features for running transactions for the cleanup and or just use Sqlite, just my two cents. I can make your code work, but will do it later in the day :)

Comment: and off course it is lightweight but Laravel development is mostly about being pragmatic and there is a big overhead to mocking functionality, there is guaranteed by the framework and will work if a database is present.

Comment: @mrhn ok thanks ! I'm going to adapt to my new tooling and environment, but I'm pretty curious on what I did wrong here anyway. I tried to mock the chained call `where->where->whereNotNull`, call mock method differently : `Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'App\Models\User');`, use allows() instead of shouldReceive ... couldnt call it with an instance, so I dont get what u mean by "call statically".

Comment: I think I finally understood your statement... you talk about my ``User::where`` call; I found some references on difficulty of stubbing static functions

Comment: But in general i have never seen a project mock Database calls in Laravel :) the way everything is tied togheter with the active records design pattern just makes it not worth your while.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was doing wrong, thanks to @mrhn ;)

Mockery allow using aliases for mocking public static functions, I wasn't aware there would be a difference at first :)

Just replacing `Mockery::mock('\App\Models\User');` by `Mockery::mock('alias:\App\Models\User');` did the trick.

Thus, it's not recommender to use this, so I guess I'll keep learning during my tests writings. As we will soon have a CI chain using directly MySQL instancied db to run against our app, and as @mrhn statement goes this way, I will consider doing real db calls in future.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem, just adding some context to @Alex and @mrhn's conversation as well as @Alex's solution.

Here is the full solution attached below, @Alex and @mrhn thanks for the contributions.

```
$mock= Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'alias:\App\Models\User');

$mock->shouldReceive('where')
     ->once()
     ->andReturn($mockedRecipients);

$this->app->instance('alias:\App\Models\User', $mock);
```

Hope this helps!